# How to set two text boxes to the same width in inkscape

Tags: inkscape, text

I have two text boxes which were created by selecting the text tool, and dragging out a rectangle of approximately the right size. Now I would like to make sure they are the same width. If I select the text boxes with the text tool, I can only resize by dragging with the mouse. If I select them with the arrow tool, I can resize by typing in a precise width on the Tool Controls Bar. But this will stretch the text and looks horrible.

Is there a way to make sure the text boxes have the same width, or will I have to eyeball it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select the text box
2. Open the XML editor in Inkscape by clicking on the XML icon in the
   top toolbar. (or click Edit > XML Editor). The XML editor will open highlighting the selected `svg:flowRoot id`
   object in the XML
3. Expand the items below the highlighted entry until you find the
   `svg:rect id`
4. Select the Width, type a new width, and press CTRL+Enter to commit
   the change.

[image]

Comment: This is not what my SVG structure looks like. I have a `svg:tspan` inside `svg:text` inside `svg:g`. There is no `svg:flowRoot`

Comment: @jameshfisher this question was not answered for you, and it's a 4 year old answer. Inkscape has had updates since I answered this, and the functionality is different now. You may need to ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the text tool for reflowing. Instead:

1. Create a rectangle.
2. Select the rectangle and the text.
3. Text > Flow into Frame.
4. Resize the rectangle to the desired flow region.

Do this once per text object, so each text object has it's own rectangle. (Flowing more than one text object into a single rectangle can make the text harder to manage rather than easier.)

Comment: I tried this as an Inkscape noob and ran into problems when I tried flowing more than one text object into a single rectangle. Once I switched to using one rectangle per text object, I found it much easier. I recommend making that explicit in the answer in order to be noob-friendly. (I tried to edit the answer myself but it looks like the edit approval process is v slow.)